# Unable to adjust line gap in highcharts-react-official 3D chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to create a 3D waterfall chart for vibration analysis. I am using Highcharts 10.2.1 and highcharts-react-official 3.1.0.
I am able to update the 3D configurations of the chart by setting the values directly inside chart object. However the same is not working for line gap.

- List item

[Demo Link](https://00zyd6.csb.app/)

[Source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-waterfall-question-00zyd6?file=/src/AngleAdjustment.tsx)

Need help understanding how to update plotOptions of highcharts - react.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is not the correct way of updating elements in Highcharts, instead, use the `update()` method.

**Simplified JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lmkza362/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried using update method in the my example, but its not working. Can you please suggest how this should work in react?

Comment: You use the `plotOptions.area` in your basic chart setup, so use the same config during the update instead of the `plotOptions.series` Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-waterfall-question-forked-7jsq68 Regards!